# OAuth2 Server and Client in Same Docker Network

Tags: docker, oauth-2.0

I am trying to run a test OAuth2 client in the same Docker network as an OAuth2 server. The idea is to allow the testing of the entire application without having to run an external OAuth2 client.

The issue I am having is that the OAuth2 server endpoint that is passed to the OAuth2 client is only available outside the Docker network on my local machine (I am using a simple nginx proxy in order to handle this, see below). So when the client attempts to get the token when the callback is called, it can't resolve the hostname (since "localhost" in the context of the client container refers to the local network of that container, but "localhost" on my browser refers to the Docker network itself). Ideally, I would like to keep using nginx as a proxy for nicer hostnames during development.

To clarify, this is currently how the process works:

1. User visits app.localhost in their browser
2. User is redirected to auth.localhost to attempt a login
3. User enters their credentials, the user is redirected to the callback
4. The callback errors, since it cannot properly get the access token from auth.localhost

Here is my docker-compose, with irrelevant parts removed for brevity:

```
version: '3'
services:
  hydra:
    image: oryd/hydra:v1.0.0-beta.9
    depends_on:
      - hydra-migrate
    command:
      serve all --dangerous-force-http
    environment:
      - OAUTH2_ISSUER_URL=http://auth.localhost/
      - OAUTH2_CONSENT_URL=http://auth.localhost/consent
      - OAUTH2_LOGIN_URL=http://auth.localhost/auth/login
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://hydra@postgres:5432/hydra?sslmode=disable
      - SYSTEM_SECRET=youReallyNeedToChangeThis
      - OAUTH2_SHARE_ERROR_DEBUG=1
      - OIDC_SUBJECT_TYPES_SUPPORTED=public,pairwise
      - OIDC_SUBJECT_TYPE_PAIRWISE_SALT=youReallyNeedToChangeThis

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - hydra
      - oauth2-test

  oauth2-test:
    build: https://github.com/chatlogs/oauth2-simple-client.git
    environment:
      - APP_URL=http://app.localhost
      - OAUTH2_URL=http://auth.localhost
      - OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID=test
      - OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET=secret
    depends_on:
      - hydra-create-client
```

And here is my nginx.conf:

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  # Proxy ChatLogs Auth and Hydra OAuth server
  server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  auth.localhost;

    location ^~ / {
      proxy_pass  http://chatlogs-auth:3000;
    }

    location ^~ /oauth2 {
      proxy_pass  http://hydra:4444/oauth2;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  app.localhost;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://oauth2-test:3000;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the error that oauth2-test shows:

```
oauth2-test_1          | { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND auth.localhost auth.localhost:80
oauth2-test_1          |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
oauth2-test_1          |   errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
oauth2-test_1          |   code: 'ENOTFOUND',
oauth2-test_1          |   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
oauth2-test_1          |   hostname: 'auth.localhost',
oauth2-test_1          |   host: 'auth.localhost',
oauth2-test_1          |   port: 80,
oauth2-test_1          |   trace:
oauth2-test_1          |    [ { method: 'POST', url: 'http://auth.localhost/oauth2/token' } ],
oauth2-test_1          |   isBoom: true,
oauth2-test_1          |   isServer: true,
oauth2-test_1          |   data: null,
oauth2-test_1          |   output:
oauth2-test_1          |    { statusCode: 502,
oauth2-test_1          |      payload:
oauth2-test_1          |       { message:
oauth2-test_1          |          'Client request error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND auth.localhost auth.localhost:80',
oauth2-test_1          |         statusCode: 502,
oauth2-test_1          |         error: 'Bad Gateway' },
oauth2-test_1          |      headers: {} },
oauth2-test_1          |   reformat: [Function] }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Similar problem here. I originally had error
```Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:3003 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost"```
then I used the IP addresses of the docker containers for the auth url and the callback. But now it gives an expiry error instead:
```omniauth: (doorkeeper) Authentication failure! Failed to open TCP connection to 172.23.0.3:3000 (execution expired): OAuth2::ConnectionError, Failed to open TCP connection to 172.23.0.3:3000 (execution expired)```
e.g. using IP:  'http://' + '172.18.0.6:3000/users/auth/doorkeeper/callback'

Answer (score 0):

Put the environment variables in quotes. It’s looking for matching service. Like http://Nginx. If you put it quotes it will be syntactically correct.